# How to convert a text/html charset=UTF-8 response to json

Tags: javascript, json, request

I'm calling an API that's returning with a content-type text/html charset=UTF-8. The result looks exactly like json when I log it. But when I log the typeof, it says it's a string. And when I try to access properties on it, I get a value of undefined.

First, I tried converting it to JSON:
const requestData = function(pageNumber) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const url = `http://www.website.com/...`;

```
request(url, (error, response, body) => {
  if (error) return reject(error)
  if (response.statusCode !== 200) return reject(response)
  console.log('Body: ', JSON.parse(body))
  resolve(body)
})
```

})
}

This throws an error:
`SyntaxError: Unexpected token m in JSON at position 1`

I also tried to escape the body before parsing it:

```
fixedstring = decodeURIComponent(escape(body))
console.log('keys: ', JSON.parse(fixedstring))
```

And I get the same error.

As mentioned, when I log the body, it looks identical to JSON:

```
...
console.log('body: ', body);
...
// Result printed to console:

    body:  {metadata:{ count:"1200", totalpages:400}, data:[{
      "city" : "Clearwater",
      "state" : "FL",
      "zip" : "33760",
    },{ 
    ...
```

How do I convert this to JSON?

Comment: hmm. Is this the exact output? If so, that's not valid JSON as the metadata keys and the data key isn't wrapped in " ". You would need: `{"metadata":{"count":"1200", "totalpages":400}, "data":[{"city" : "Clearwater","state" : "FL","zip" : "33760"}]}` to have a valid JSON string.

Comment: Yeah, that's a good point. Yeah I copied and pasted that part directly from the console. That's what's causing the `Unexpected token m in JSON at position 1` error

Comment: Any ideas on how to make this an accessible object @Shilly ?

Comment: That is a very strange api....you sure there aren't parameters you can set to return json as response format?

Comment: Indeed. Maybe some tinkering with http headers will automatically give you back JSON. Else you'll have to manually write a parser for it. If the format is exactly the same, in this case I would just cut the data array part out of the string and JSON.parse() that valid part. If the format can vary, you're a bit more limited. Either regex or maybe the new Function() constructor can help, although I would advice against it, so preferably we figure out how to have the API return valid json. accepts-encoding application/json maybe?

Comment: @Shilly, Even `requests.post(URL, verify=False, headers=headers).json()` gives the same error `raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
`. Any suggestions? Secondlty, does by parsing you are trying to suggest on the lines of using [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) ?

Comment: Did u got solution for this issue..i too have same issue..help me to solve this...thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

in my case, I used `await response.text()` rather than `await response.json()`

Comment: This does not answer the question.